# Can't select polygon after drawing it

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to interactively draw individually styled polygons atop a map. The drawing works well, but I can't seem to select the polygons once drawn to modify them. I suspect I'm confused about where they are actually being drawn into:

```
var drawLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: new ol.source.Vector() 
     });

map.addLayer( drawLayer );                                      

var select = new ol.interaction.Select();

map.addInteraction( new ol.interaction.Modify({
            features: select.getFeatures()
            }); 

map.addInteraction( draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({    
            source: drawLayer.getSource(),
            type: "Polygon" 
            }); 

draw.on('drawend', function( e ) {
        var sty = new ol.style.Style( {                                 
            fill: new ol.style.Fill( { color: newCol } )
            });
        e.feature.setStyle( sty );
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to add the interaction by extending the interaction defaults before the select will become active. Just adding it using `map.addInteraction()` is neccesary, but not sufficient.

```
    featureSelect=new ol.interaction.Select();  

    map=new ol.Map( {
            interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([featureSelect]),    
             //...  
           });
```